# Horizontal scroll only on chrome mobile BUG

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a website and on the mobile version (only on chrome browser - firefox works fine ) I have a horizontal scroll that I cant't get rid of. It's driving me crazy. I tried overflow-x:hidden; on html and body tags and it still doesn't work. I ran a script to find if there is any element on the DOM that exceeds the width of the viewport, but I found nothing. The link is [orhideeaevents.ro](https://orhideeaevents.ro) . Here is a picture:

[image: problem]

Thanks in advance, guys, and sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Is the logo that is present in the header.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `CSS` code, it fixes the problem:

```
html , body {
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

.custom-logo {
    width: unset;
    height: 100px !important;
}

#masthead {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm...though I have set position:absolute; on the same container on another project and it didn't have any problem...

Comment: Absolute position is for some limited purposes to locate an alement in a specified position of parent element. So be careful to use that

Answer (score 0):

I have inspected your page and I think the problem is in your logo. For some reason it does not want to apply 60px rule that you have set for it in mobile view. You can fix it by applying width: -webkit-fill-available; or width: fit-content; to img element. It worked for me in mobile view on Chrome browser but I am not sure if this solves your problem in 100%.